# Is there any way to escape the "good listener" room?

Tags: portal-2

In Chapter 4, after Wheatley busted me out and I did a bit of running, Glados opened up the "final" test chamber and asked me to complete it. (This is the room with the heart on the wall, and you get the "good listener" achievement for entering it.) Upon entering the room, the exits all close up and the neurotoxin starts flowing.

Is there any way to escape before the neurotoxin kills me? I thought perhaps a portal could be placed outside the room before entering, but I don't see any suitable surfaces.

Comment: This is just one of at least two achievements that kills you if you complete it... the other I can think of is Pit Boss.

Comment: OTOH after escaping Whetley's trap (lots of spikey plates) you can come back when he asks you, and listen to some hilarious texts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The moment you enter the room, a script is activated which kills you when the room is flooded, regardless of whether you're in it or not.

This means that even if there were a way to escape it, you would still die.

Answer (score 8):

I tried escaping this room a few times, but there doesn't appear to be a way out. That's probably part of the 'Good Listener' achievement - so the game can brand the player as a fool :p

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't a portal surface outside the room, there isn't a way to legally get out of it.

If you can place portals inside the room you could use the speed-run glitch to shoot a Portal from the outside of the map; but then; I think you will still die because the script kills you regardless of where you are. It's the same way as you die in co-op during such event...

Comment: @ArdaXi: The script would place the block, hence, the script kills you. It doesn't matter how this happens under the hood, I'm trying to keep this as general as possible as this could as well be read as a plot script... **Edit:** Oops, it could indeed depend on whether it is extended outside the room. For which we need to noclip or use a network editor to test this out, but they at least do this outside the room for co-op missions...

Comment: @ArdaXi: There is a trigger brush inside of the room to detect when you enter and is has a delayed output. The question is whether this output enables a trigger_hurt, which would have a predetermined size, or if it triggers an event that directly references the player. If the screen fades to white, it's probably an event, and if the screen flashes red as it does when you take damage, it's probably a brush.