# What happens if you choose GLaDOS' way in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

Spoiler warning!

During the first escape attempt in Portal 2 (when GLaDOS is still in charge) she opens a door for you which you can choose to go through instead of following Wheatley (the blue-eyed ball). What happens if you go there?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20434/is-there-any-way-to-escape-the-good-listener-room

Comment: Related activity : When Wheatley says 'come back' to you, go back.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

GLaDOS closes the door and the wall. Then she fills the room with a deadly neurotoxin and you die.

Here's a video showing that scene:

Comment: And you get an achievement, so worth it.

Comment: I did this the first time I played - I am so weak!

Comment: I did this on my second playthrough, not realizing it was "wrong".  After having done it "properly" on the first one.

Comment: I just wanted to see the deer

Comment: You need to step on the button before you die.

Comment: @Juan Manuel: It's a beautiful day out. Yesterday I saw a deer. If you come back, we can ride an elevator all the way up to the break room, and I'll tell you about the time I saw a deer again.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro I didn't see the deer today, but I did see some humans. But with you here I have more test subjects than I'll ever need.