# What is there behind the door in Portal 2's "The Surprise" chamber?

Tags: portal-2

Assuming you didn't die, by cheating or whatever, is there anything interesting after that door?

Comment: Are you referring to [this part of the game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24046)?

Comment: Voting to reopen -  I was just asking for clarification, this is not a duplicate...

Comment: Yes, I mean  that part. I want to know what there is beyond the door.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing 'interesting' behind that door.
Here is a screenshot.
[image]